# Derive keywords from search text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to generate keywords to search and display some content from the database.I have given a sample search text and keywords that I would like to derive from the keyword. Can someone guide me on how to implement the logic to get the keywords from a dynamic search string as shown below?

```
var searchText='My name is John santose mayer'

var Keywords={ 

  1: 'My name is John santose mayer',

  2: 'My name is johns santose',

  3: 'My name is John',

  4: 'My name is',

  5: 'My name'

  6: 'My'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this using `reduce`?

```js
var searchText='My name is John santose mayer';


let keywords = searchText.split(' ').reduce((prev, next) => {
  const concatWith =  prev[prev.length - 1] ?  prev[prev.length - 1] + ' ' : ''
  return [ ...prev, concatWith + next]
 
}, []).reverse()

console.log(keywords)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const keywords = searchText.split(' ');
const phrases = [];
for(let length = keywords.length; length > 0; length--) {
  phrases.push(keywords.slice(0, length).join(' '));
}
```

Comment: Split will not give the search string i have shown in the query

Answer (score 0):

Simple combination of `split`, `map`, `slice` and `reduce` should do the trick.

```js
const foo = "My name is John santose mayer"
    .split(" ")
    .map<string>((_, i, arr) => arr.slice(0, arr.length - i).join(" "))
    // [
    //     "My name is John santose mayer",
    //     "My name is John santose",
    //     "My name is John",
    //     "My name is",
    //     "My name",
    //     "My"
    //   ]
    .reduce<{ [key: number]: string }>((acc, curr, i) => {
        acc[i + 1] = curr;
        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(foo);
// {
//     "1": "My name is John santose mayer",
//     "2": "My name is John santose",
//     "3": "My name is John",
//     "4": "My name is",
//     "5": "My name",
//     "6": "My"
// }
```